# Delete Specific Row in Custom ListView

Tags: android

I have a CustomAdapter class, which points to 4 widgets in its getView method (3 TextViews and 1 Button). I would like to be able to click on the Button in ANY row and have that specific row be deleted. I set an onClick method for my Button in my getView method in the Adapter class. The problem is that every time I hit the button, it deletes the last row created instead of the specific one that I want. Here is my getView method:

```
    @Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_custom_row,null);
        Button deleteBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.customRowDeleteButton);
        TextView name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.customRowContactName);
        TextView phone = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.customRowContactNumber);
        TextView email = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.customRowContactEmail);

        name.setText(names.get(position));
        phone.setText(phoneNumbers.get(position));
        email.setText(emails.get(position));

        phone.setOnClickListener(this);

        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              //This is the Issue I think, the position number
                names.remove(position);
                phoneNumbers.remove(position);
                emails.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this....

```
@Override
        public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final Holder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                 holder = new Holder();
                 convertView = ((LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.contacts_custom_row, parent, false);
                 holder.deleteBtn = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.customRowDeleteButton);
                 holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.customRowContactName);
                 holder.phone = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.customRowContactNumber);
                 holder.email = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.customRowContactEmail);
                 convertView.setTag(holder);
             } else {
                 holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
             }

                holder.name.setText(names.get(position));
                holder.phone.setText(phoneNumbers.get(position));
                holder.email.setText(emails.get(position));
                holder.pos = position;

                holder.phone.setOnClickListener(this);

                holder.deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        names.remove(holder.pos);
                        phoneNumbers.remove(holder.pos);
                        emails.remove(holder.pos);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });

            }
            return convertView;
        }

        static class Holder{
            Button deleteBtn ;
            TextView name, phone, email;
            int pos;
        }
```

Comment: The SDK isn't recognizing Holder as a class

Comment: where are you adding this class. you have to add it outside the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

No you are doing illegal removing. You should get the position of List item clicked and pass it to your function to remove item from the list view.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a global variable `int pos = 0;` then

Change this

```
TextView phone = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.customRowContactNumber);
        TextView email = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.customRowContactEmail);

        name.setText(names.get(position));
        phone.setText(phoneNumbers.get(position));
```

To this

```
    TextView phone = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.customRowContactNumber);
    TextView email = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.customRowContactEmail);
    pos = names.get(position);
    name.setText(names.get(position));
    phone.setText(phoneNumbers.get(position));
```

And use the `pos` into the remove Button Listener to remove it from your List. The thing is that if your list populates from database you got to remove the item from database as well otherwise each time you start the app the list item that you have deleted will still be there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `onListItemClick` instead. Place this inside the `Activity` or `Fragment` where you declare your `ListView`, rather than in your `Adapter`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private ListView listView;
    private MyListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       //Once listView is initialised and your adapter set
       listVew.setOnItemClickListener(this);
//...
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
        int id = view.getId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.customRowDeleteBtn:
                names.remove(position);
                phoneNumbers.remove(position);
                emails.remove(position);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
        }
    }
```